# Wcf returning ususual response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-rest

I am trying to return a list

```
public List<tblcourse> GetData(string value)
{
    testEntities1 db = new testEntities1();

    int v = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    testEntities1 t = new testEntities1();
    var u = (from g in t.tblcourses
             select new  { g.C_Id,  g.C_Name }).ToList();

    List<tblcourse> lisstt = new List<tblcourse>();

    foreach (var item in u)
    {
        tblcourse b = new tblcourse();
        b.C_Id = item.C_Id;
        b.C_Name = item.C_Name;
        lisstt.Add(b);
    }

    return lisstt;
}
```

From client when I consume this service , I get the following response from the service when I execute client code

```
string strServiceUrl1 = "htttp://localhost:1967/Service1.svc/GetData/" + id;

HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest1 = WebRequest.Create(strServiceUrl1) as HttpWebRequest;
objHttpWebRequest1.Method = "GET";
objHttpWebRequest1.ContentType = "application/json-urlencoded";

StreamReader onjStreamReader1 = new StreamReader(objHttpWebRequest1.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string strResponse1 = onjStreamReader1.ReadToEnd().ToString();

List<Course> cc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Course>>(strResponse1);
return View(cc);
```

The following is the response I am getting as `response` and because of that I am not able to `deserialize` the response into a list.

```
<ArrayOftblcourse xmlns="htttp://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/app2" 
                  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <tblcourse>
      <C_Id>1</C_Id>
      <C_Name>DOt Net</C_Name>
   </tblcourse>
   <tblcourse>
      <C_Id>2</C_Id>
      <C_Name>EF</C_Name>
   </tblcourse>
   <tblcourse>
      <C_Id>3</C_Id>
      <C_Name>MVC</C_Name>
   </tblcourse>
   <tblcourse>
      <C_Id>4</C_Id>
      <C_Name>MS SQL</C_Name>
   </tblcourse>
</ArrayOftblcourse>
```

Contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetData/{value}") ]
List<tblcourse> GetData(string value);
```

Error while deserializing is

> Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Autogenerated class file of `tbclcourses`

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(tblstudent))]
public partial class tblcourse
{
        public tblcourse()
        {
            this.tblstudents = new HashSet<tblstudent>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int C_Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string C_Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<tblstudent> tblstudents { get; set; }
}
```

`web.config` files webHttpBinding:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBinding" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             transferMode="StreamedResponse">
       <security mode="None">
           <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
       </security>
       <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="100000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
   </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Please provide how your service contract look like.

Comment: @dotnetstep : Please see my edit. I am not able to deserilize a string like this.

Comment: @marc_s : I am getting the the error as

Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: did you configure WebHttpBidning and webhttp behavior in configuration file ?

Comment: Please provide the class file of tblcourse

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Course>>(strResponse1);` You're using `WebHttpBinding` which is (from MSDN) *The WCF Web Programming Model allows developers to expose WCF Web services through HTTP requests that use "plain old XML" (POX) style messaging instead of SOAP-based messaging.* How is the JSON serializer going to deserialize XML?

Comment: @ta.speot.is : So, how can i deserialize the same.? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your webinvoke should look like this. ( Specify response format)

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetData/{value}",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json) ]
List<tblcourse> GetData(string value);
```

Comment: +One for understanding the subtle nuance of XML and JSON and how XML is not JSON.

Comment: @dotnetstep : Can I reduce the code and still get the same result.? Can i skip the foreach loop?

Comment: If both entity are same then you should get same result. You can try with return only var u =  (from g in t.tblcourses
             select new  { g.C_Id,  g.C_Name }).ToList(); return u;